# generate multiple different random numbers in C++/C?

Tags: c++, random, hash

I know that rand() % N would be able to generate a long integer between 0 and N-1 if N is not too large. However, now I'd lke to generate about 0.1N number of integers from 0 to N-1, would there be some quick way to do this?

When N is small, it might be possible to keep an array and check if the number has been generated before, but this becomes very slow as N increases. Moreover, with a poor seed it might even generate the same number over and over again and form a dead loop.

Also, I guess it is possible to use hashing to distribute the number, and open addressing just simply makes every generated number go to the next empty spot (for instance, if 23 is generated twice, try 23+4, 23+9, 23+16...) But this, too, is slow for large datasize.

So, is there any good way to generate a bunch of disjoint random numbers in acceptable time? Thank you!

P.S.the size of N is quite large, at least at the order of 10^6-10^7, and would be best if it can run at 10^8. (Actually the problem is a boolean array of N, and flip randomly 10% of it) If a "shuffling" algorithm can be implemented it will also work.

Comment: First, use `<random>` instead of `rand()`. Second, you can insert into a `std::set` to check for duplicates.

Comment: `rand() % N` is terrible. Don't use it.

Comment: You might want to check, what c++ standard [Pseudo-random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) offers for your purposes.

Comment: Quantify at least the order of magnitude of N in bits otherwise a solution could be better than another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I agree with other commenters about using `<random>` or Boost Mersenne Twister in preference to `rand()`.

If your true objective is to flip *about* 10% of the bits in an array, why not tackle that directly?   Mersenne Twister can already produce Uniform(0,1)'s as well as integers, alternatively if you use `<random>` you can scale by `RAND_MAX + 1` to convert to a Uniform(0,1).  Iterate through your array of bits, for each index generate a value `u` with a Uniform(0,1) distribution, and if `u <= 0.1` flip the bit.

If it's gotta be exactly 10%, then your choices are

1) Acceptance/rejection: generate indices at random, track the ones you've already generated in a hash table, and try again if you get a duplicate.  People think this is a lot less efficient than it really is.  With a target of 0.1N, initially you will produce virtually no duplicates and towards the end it will be about 1 out of 10, yielding 10/9 or 1.11 attempts as the expected number of attempts before you get a new value. The probability of it taking more than 3 or 4 attempts is vanishingly small.  Think of it as about 5% average overhead to get your target set (since the actual overhead ranges from 0 at the beginning to 11% towards the end).

2) Shuffling: You'll need to create an array with all 10^7 or 10^8 values, but the good news is that you only have to shuffle 10% of it.  Once you've permuted the first 10%, you can stop and that subset is your selection. Good run-time efficiency at a cost of more storage.

Comment: acceptance/rejection is actually working pretty well! In fact the past few days I used exactly this method to write the program, and it ran in just seconds. Although for rand(), it has a high possibility of generating the same number over and over again (due to small period, I guess), but for mt19937() it is perfectly fine.

Comment: About shuffling, though, it would be more storage-efficient to just store an array of 10^8 of 0's and 1's (which denote "chosen/unchosen"), instead of 10^8 of long integer. Then one would only have to flip the first 10% of 0's into 1's, then permutate the whole array. But would there be any efficient way to do so? I mean to shuffle a really large array...

Comment: @MikeWong Check out the second variant of [Fisher-Yates shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_Shuffle#The_modern_algorithm). If you loop from 0 to `k-1` rather than `n-1`, the first `k` elements now contain indices from anywhere in the index set. The array has to have all possible indices so that each index has a chance of being in the subset, but you only have to perform exchanges for the desired number of elements.

Comment: Shuffling *is* efficient, it's O(n) to shuffle n items.

Comment: Thanks! I just checked the wiki page and indeed the Fisher-Yates shuffling is very concise and only O(n). Also, is there any built-in C++ functions for Fisher-Yates shuffling? (Since even Mersenne Twister is included in the C++ package..this might be as well?) Would simply calling shuffle() be efficient?

Comment: Yes I see your point, but if indeed I generate 1-10^8 an put it in order in an array, shuffling the first 10% would only include a permutation of the first 10% indices wouldn't it? Or should I shuffle the whole lot and pick the first 10% (but if whole array has to be shuffled anyway, a 0/1 implementation would be more space-efficient since bool only takes 1 byte compared to 4 for long int)

Comment: If you look at how the shuffling algorithm works, any element in the array can end up in the locations you've processed so far.  So no, you only need to apply the shuffle to the first 10% of locations, then use those to determine which bits to flip.

Comment: It's been about 20 years since I used C++ extensively, so I can't tell you about the libraries.  It seems likely that BOOST would provide a shuffle, but it would probably default to the entire array.  Since it's only a few lines of coding, I'd implement your own short-circuited version.

Comment: Oh indeed, I see. So the point is to do the iteration using i from 0 to 0.1*n? And also the algorithm doesn't seem to be complex, so yes it might be easily implemented by hand. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: "track the ones you've already generated in a hash table, and try again if you get a duplicate" - if the array is starting in an all-true or all-false state, it can be used directly - otherwise creating a second bitset would more space efficient and faster than a hash table.

Answer (score 3):

The classical solution is to call `shuffle`; this can even produce N random numbers between 0 and N-1.

If you worry about bad seeds, get one of the decent RNG's from `<random>` instead of using the old C one.

Comment: Indeed. Generate an array with values 0..N-1 (or whatever range you need) and then shuffle it. That ensures that each value only exists once and that the order is random.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Boost Mersenne Twister](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp) for much faster and better pseudo-random numbers to begin with. It uses a seed engine and you wont get the same seed (you still might get two numbers which are the same - but that is randomness).

Answer (score 0):

A Bloom filter is a very efficient way to implement relaxed set semantics that meets your needs. All you need to know is if an element is definitely not in the set, then you can accept it to your list of random values.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Quoting the wikipedia:
a query returns either "possibly in set" or "definitely not in set"

Shuffle **does not do what** you want:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/
In specific, it does not remove duplicate values.

The set container, referenced in one of the comments will work, but have all the costs you were worried about in your question.

Answer (score 0):

srand(-time(NULL));

This will call the system time as seed and each time generate a different random number. And in this case the seed is never poor! and don't forget to call the relative Header file.

Comment: `rand()` only generates a different random number for a specific number of calls to `rand()` known as the *period* (I think POSIX requires >= 2^31 which is good for this, but on non-POSIX systems it could be an issue), `RAND_MAX` is only guaranteed to be at least 32767 so may not be directly useful for 1e7..1e8 elements, and even if RAND_MAX happens to be more than that, after '%'-ing with N you will still get "collisions" so that has to be handled somehow.

Comment: How is that relevant to my answer ?

Comment: You claimed "each time generate a different random number", so I pointed out that's true for a specific number of calls to rand(), and that in a worst-case implementation that specific number is only 32768.  Pretty direct relevance IMHO.  Just as importantly, the question needs to get ~1e8 distinct numbers and RAND_MAX may be massively less, and you haven't explained how to cope with that disparity.  Separately, srand takes an unsigned argument, and "seed is never poor" isn't true - people run programs in the same second and find they're getting the same pseudo-random number stream.  Cheers.